# Nexus S OTA 4.0.4 problem?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, ota-update

I get 4.0.4 OTA with my Nexus S today. After downloaded the update package, i click "Reboot to install", but unfortunately the phone did't reboot successfully, so i boot it by myself.
I checked the `android version` in the settings, it's still 4.0.3, and the system update never 
noticed me to update to 4.0.4 again. Does this means i can't get the 4.0.4 later? How can i try to install it again?

My phone was rooted before, Any help will be very appreciated.

Anyone got the same problem as me? it frustrated me.

Comment: Especially if you were already offered the OTA, consider a trick from the Nexus One days.  Open up your dialer and dial the following number: `*#*#checkin#*#*`.  This was suspected at some time to coax the system into checking for available OTA updates.  As there is a good chance this won't work, I'll leave this a comment.

Comment: @ctt I tried and received `checkin succeeded` notification, and when i click it, it disappear.

Comment: If that doesn't work to jumpstart the OTA checks, it may just be a case of waiting it out.  If you're impatient, though, there are those .zips that have been floating around; but use at your own risk.

Comment: @ctt All right, i will wait it out, also, i want to know anyone got the same problem as me, it frustrated me. Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I unroot my Nexus S (If you don't know how to unroot Nexus S, you can see [this](http://nexusshacks.com/nexus-s-hacks/how-to-unroot-nexus-s-i9020ti9020ai9023/)), then received the OTA again and upgrade to 4.0.4 successfully.

> When updating the android, the screen maybe dark for a while, just be patient and wait it
>   restart automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `Settings -> About phone (at the bottom) -> System updates. If there's nothing there try the 'Check now' option and this should make the phone check for new updates.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: I have tried this, but it didn't works. Anyway, Thanks for your answer, I found someone may faced the same problem, he unroot the phone and received the OTA again. I will try.